# Unable to access third-party bitbucket workspace repos via AWS codestar connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline

I am in a project which is creating a AWS codepipline for a source in a bitbucket repo.
while creating the AWS codepipeline it is need to give a repository provider connection through aws codestar connection to clone the source from a third party repo. In my case, source code resides in a bitbucket repo and it is a company owned workspace. I have default developer access for that workspace and I am the one creating the bitbucket connection for the AWS codepipeline.

[image]

In here, nemozon workspace is the company workspace and verse722 is my own workspace.

I have created codestar connection to mybitbucket account and configured it as follows.

[image]

but when I check the repos in aws portal through that codestar connect, it is only showing repos inside verse722 workspace but not ones in nemozon. As shown in this picture:

[image]

Except, I can actually see a nemozon workspace repo using my bitbucket portal as follows.

[image]

I need to make nemozon repos allow me to clone for codepipline through the codestar connection.

Answer (score 0):

A codestar connection to a workspace requires authorisation by a workspace administrator. You will need to ask an admin for the nemozon bitbucket workspace to create the codestar connection in the aws account.

Once this is done you can use it to access the workspace.